# After Effect - Triangle Wave (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, geometry, expression

I'm trying to control a parameter with AE expressions and I need a triangle wave. I've got this so far:

```
freq = 20;
amplitude = 8; 

m = amplitude;
i = time*freq;

m - (i % (2*m) - m);
```

Unfortunately this gives a saw wave (see below) and my math's a bit rusty, any takers?

Thanks!

PJ

http://i25.photobucket.com/albums/c73/pjburnhill/Screenshot2010-04-09at153815.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to get a triangle wave from here would be to subtract `m/2` and take the absolute value. Alternatively, use `f = m - abs(i % (2*m) - m)`.

Comment: See above, AE doesn't seem to allow abs... Am I missing out something here?

Comment: Use `Math.abs()`. It's in the Javascript pulldown, I think.

Comment: Thanks John! That's it, got it working.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Just a (hopefully) final question, how can I get the triangle wave to give me negative values as well? So oscillating between i.e. 16 and -16?

The line is currently like this: x = m - Math.abs(i % (2*m) - m);

Comment: What's it oscillating between right now?

Comment: Whis this code it oscillates between 0 and 8:

freq = 20;nd 
amplitude = 8; 

m = amplitude;
i = time*freq;

m - Math.abs(i % (2*m) - m);

How can I get it to go to -8?

Thanks!

Comment: Make it `2 * Math.abs(...) - m`.

Comment: Hmm... still doesn't give negative values.. now oscillates between 0 and 16. Code: `2 *  Math.abs(i % (2*m) - m);`

Comment: You didn't write what I said. Keep the part in the `abs` the same as in post, but make it `2 * Math.abs(...) - m`.

Comment: Ahhh... my bad! So finally this code works:
`2 * Math.abs(i % (2*m) - m) - m;`

Thanks John, very much appreciated!

Comment: Erhm... and how would I get the wave to start from negative value instead of a positive?

Comment: Shift `i` accordingly (e.g. by making `i +/- [something]`).